# Is it necessary to perform cross validation when you have large enough sample size?

Tags: testing, cross-validation, sampling, variance

I have a very large sample size, I split it 80/20 into training and testing. Furthermore, I split my training with 80/20 into training and validation. I checked the variance of my metrics and they are quite satisfactory. Do you think it would add value if I perform cross validation?